# errors in BufferReader when trying to get response from Web API

Tags: android, api, get, inputstream

It seems to be that "today" is not my day, so i trying to get data from web-API by GET response, which contains a JSON structure. I'd like to mention that is not my first "json-get" app, i have already make an apps with loading data by API and all things goes very good until today. So i often get an 2 errors in same line when trying to connect.

- `NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`
- `java.io.EOFException at at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)`,

approximately every 4 app-launch crashes with one of this errors. I already tried to launch my app in different devices and emulator, but still get this errors. Is it a bug? I'd like to note that i haven't any internet problems with devices or API, you can try it by yourself [here](http://demxp.myftp.org/mkr/oper.php?act=getnewsall).

**UPDATED**
now still be the 1st problem with invalid int, the code looks like this :

```
 public static void getNewsList(final OnLoadFinishedListener listener) {
    if (listener != null) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread_getNewsList");
                ArrayList<News> news = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(mURL_API + "oper.php?act=getnewsall");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    conn.connect();
             //still getting an error in this line -->
                    if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
             //<--
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), HTTP.UTF_8));
                        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        try {
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                buffer.append(line);
                            }

                        } finally {
                            in.close();
                        }
                        JsonArray request = (JsonArray) mGparser.parse(buffer.toString());
                        in.close();

                        news = mGson.fromJson(request, new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>() {
                        }.getType());
                        listener.onLoadFinished(news);
                        conn.disconnect();
                    } else
                        throw new NoInternetException("Bad internet request, response code is "
                                + conn.getResponseCode());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    listener.onNotConnected();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your News class? I guess you have int newsid; inside class but in json newsid is represented as String. This is string in json "newsid":"1" and this is number "newsid": 1.

Comment: @vandzi yeah, newsid declrared as int in News.class, but why an error happens in "Buffer" line, not where i'm getting Json from inputstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to make your "bad today" to vary good today

```
public static void getNewsList(final OnLoadFinishedListener listener) {
        if (listener != null) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread_getNewsList");
                    ArrayList<News> news = null;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(mURL_API + "oper.php?act=getnewsall");
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                        conn.connect();
            //Here i get an error -->
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),HTTP.UTF_8));
            //<--

                        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();


                        String line = null;
                        try {
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                buffer.append(line);
                            }

                        } finally {
                            in.close();
                        }


                        JsonArray request = (JsonArray) mGparser.parse(buffer.toString());
                        in.close();

                        news = mGson.fromJson(request, new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>() {
                        }.getType());
                        listener.onLoadFinished(news);
                        conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        listener.onNotConnected();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: great thanks, but that problem still be, and always when i reinstal my app, i didn't know what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

For solving NumberFormatException see my comment to question.
After conn.connect() try to place this code:

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
Gson gson = new Gson();
//I don't know what is type of news but based on your code
news = gson.fromJson(isr, new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>());
```